# C++ Pi Estimation Program Not Working Properly

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a program that estimates Pi values using three different formulas pictured here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtaG.png .

This is my program so far:

```
{
double leibniz = 0.0; // pi value calculated from Leibniz                        
double counter = 0.0; // starting value                                          
double eulerall = 0.0; // value calculated from Euler (all integers)             
double eulerodd = 0.0; // value calculated from Euler (odds)                     
double eulerallans; // pi value calculated from Euler series (all integers)      
double euleroddans; // pi value calculated from Euler series (odd integers)      
int terms;
bool negatives = false;

cin >> terms;
cout << fixed << setprecision(12); // set digits after decimal to 12             
while(terms > counter){
leibniz = 4*(pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter+1) + leibniz;
eulerall = (1/pow(counter+1,2)) + eulerall;
eulerodd = 32*(pow(-1, counter)) / (pow(2*counter + 1, 3)) + eulerodd;
counter++;
eulerallans = sqrt(eulerall*6);
euleroddans =  pow(eulerodd, 1.0/3.0);
cin >> terms;
if (terms < 0){
if(!negatives)
  negatives=true;
}
}

cout << right << setw(14) << "# TERMS" << setw(15) << "LEIBINZ" << setw(15) << "\
EULER-ALL" << setw(15) << "EULER-ODD" << endl;
cout << right << setw(14) << terms << " " << leibniz << " " << eulerallans << " "\
<< euleroddans <<endl;
cout << "There were " << negatives << " negative values read" << endl;

return 0;

}
```

The sample input file that I am using is:

1

6

-5

100

-1000000

0

And the sample output for this input file is:

1 4.000000000000 2.449489742783 3.174802103936

6 2.976046176046 2.991376494748 3.141291949057

100 3.131592903559 3.132076531809 3.141592586052

When I run my program all I get as an output is:

# TERMS        LEIBINZ      EULER-ALL      EULER-ODD
             1

4.000000000000

2.449489742783

1.000000000000

So, I have two problems with my program: 
1) It is only reading the first value in the input file and stopping. 
2) The equation for eulerodd seems to be off, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

EDIT: Thanks to @RaphaelMiedl, I solved problem 2. Now I only have problem 1 to deal with.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `355/113` is accurate enough to locate a car on the surface of the Earth. `3.141592653589` could probably locate an atom in the Oort cloud(*). Do we really _need_ more accuracy :-) * I've tested the first hypothesis, the second is just hyperbole.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to go through all of your code but

```
euleroddans =  pow(32*eulerodd, 1/3);
```

immediately jumped me when I skimmed over it. `1/3` is integer arithmetic and gives you 0. Probably not what you wanted, you probably want `1.0/3.0` or something of the like there.

---

Now a bit of a late addition since I had time to look at your code again. @paddy is right that you only got one input statement in your code.

I'd probably put the whole pi calculation and outputting in a function and then loop over the input like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void my_pi_func(int term);

int main()
{
    int term;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(12); // set digits after decimal to 12         

    while (cin >> term){
        my_pi_func(term);
    }

    return 0;

}

void my_pi_func(int term)
{
    if (term <= 0){
        cout << "\n\nNegative value or 0 read\n\n" << endl;
        return;
    }

    double leibniz = 0.0; // pi value calculated from Leibniz                     
    int counter = 0; // starting value                                       
    double eulerall = 0.0; // value calculated from Euler (all integers)          
    double eulerodd = 0.0; // value calculated from Euler (odds)                  
    double eulerallans = 0.0; // pi value calculated from Euler series (all integers)   
    double euleroddans = 0.0; // pi value calculated from Euler series (odd integers)

    while(term > counter){
    leibniz = 4*(pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter+1) + leibniz;
    eulerall = (1/pow(counter+1,2)) + eulerall;
    eulerodd = (pow(-1, counter)) / (pow(2*counter + 1, 3)) + eulerodd;
    counter++;
    eulerallans = sqrt(eulerall*6);
    euleroddans =  pow(32*eulerodd, 1.0/3.0);
    }
    cout << right << setw(14) << "# TERMS" << setw(15) << "LEIBINZ" << setw(15)
    << "EULER-ALL" << setw(15) << "EULER-ODD" << endl;
    cout << right << setw(14) << term << " " << leibniz << " " << eulerallans 
    << " " << euleroddans <<endl;

}
```

You can see a [working version here](http://ideone.com/x51u8n). Note that I made some more slight adjustments. For one I changed `terms` into `term` since that plural s was somehow bothering me. Also I changed `counter` to be an `int` since a counter as `double` variable doesn't make sense in my opinion. Also I changed how negative/0 values output. But all in all you should get what you should change if you compare with yours.

Comment: Oh wow... I can't believe I overlooked that. I just changed it and it is now compiling correctly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @user3409117, technically, it was _always_ compiling correctly, it's just that this particular problem was a PEBKAC one :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Haha, you're right. So now my only problem is that my program only reads the first value in the input file. Do you guys know how to make it so it reads all the values?

Comment: @user3409117 You could start by reading more than one value.  Currently you are just doing `cin >> terms`.  Perhaps you want to loop it.

Comment: Hey @paddy, I added cin >> terms into the while loop, but it completely messes up the calculations for the input file with multiple integers. Although, when I test it with only one integer, the calculations come out correct.

Comment: @user3409117 I edited my answer for your second problem too. I'd highly suggest looking at the output it gives [here](http://ideone.com/x51u8n) too.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, but we haven't gone over the void function in class yet, so we aren't allowed to use it. Is there a way of looping the input without the void function? Sorry for all the questions, but I'm trying different combinations from my class notes, but none of them seem to be working. I've tried several ways nesting cin >> terms into the while statement, but they're not working.

Comment: @user3409117 You can't just throw it in any old loop willy-nilly.  You need to actually think about it.  I was just pointing out that you only read one value from the file.

Comment: @user3409117 instead of using `my_pi_func` inside the while loop just put all your logic (what's currently inside the function) inside the curly braces of the while loop. Also I'd suggest looking at some class notes about looping and input again, since it seems that you got some problems with them still.

Comment: @paddy, of course! I have a whole bunch of examples in my lecture notes, but all of them just have the "cin >>" put in at the end of the while loop, but it's not working when I do that.

Comment: @user3409117 I won't edit the answer since I don't want to bump it again but here is a [working example](http://ideone.com/Zavfft) of the code without the function. I basically dumped all the code inside the function into the while loop and changed the `return` in the loop to a `continue` so that the calculation and output still get skipped when 0 or negative values get entered.

Comment: Thank you so much Raphael for all your help! I just need to do some formatting, but its compiling correctly. I'll definitely take your advice and study up on my looping.